# Widgets not appearing in homepage sidebar in wordpress

Tags: php, widget, wordpress

I have added some widgets to my homepage sidebar, but they are not appearing on the home page. If I add some widgets to the main sidebar it will appear in home page, and other pages.

I am new to Wordpress, I don't know how to solve this issue, and also default widgets are not appearing. I am using `wp-bootstrap` theme and a Q/A paid plugin.

Comment: how did you call widgets on homepage, will you elaborate some piece of code??

Comment: Not did any codes, i have drag and drop the widgets to the homepage sidebar

Comment: when i tried with my localhost it is coming, but in production it is not, difference is i have installed a Q/A plugin in production

Comment: In the dashboard General settings, do you have a static home page set there?

Comment: Yes, In general settings-> readings-> Front page displays static page(radio)-> front page home

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all register your homepage sidebar in function.php

```
function Name_widgets_init() {
    register_sidebar(array(
        'name' =>   __( 'homepage sidebar', 'test theme' ),
        'id' =>     'sidebar_homepage',
        'description' => __( 'This Wwill appear on homepage sidebar', 'test theme' )
    ) );
} 
add_action( 'widgets_init', 'Name_widgets_init' );
```

Than use this trick to display your widgets, put the following code to the home page where you want to add sidebar

```
<div class="sidebar_home" id="sidebar_left">

<?php if ( is_active_sidebar( 'sidebar-left' ) ) : ?>
        <div id="secondary" class="widget-area" role="complementary">
            <?php dynamic_sidebar( 'sidebar_homepage' ); ?>
        </div>
    <?php endif; ?>

</div>
```

**Finally Note**
i have used a div in last chunk of code please write your own CSS to control it.

Comment: what is the 'test theme', it is related to theme name?

Comment: it is created a new tab in menu called as home, and i have added the 2nd code in my home page but the code is directly appearing

Comment: test theme is your theme name

Comment: actually i answered as your i got your question, i read four time to understand your question :)